# Changing layer properties for 3D View using PyQGIS

Tags: qgis-3, 3d, pyqgis-3

I would like to change the default settings in 3D View.

- No symbols to Single Symbol
- Altitude clamping from Relative to Absolute
- Change colors for Diffuse, Ambient and Specular

Changing by hand works fine but is impractical for 10+ layers. I would like to automate it with Python.
I have looked into the [3D Library Python API](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/3d/index.html) but I have not been able to get this to work.

I have written some code:

```py
import qgis._3d as d

wkt = "MULTIPOLYGON Z(((0 0 0, 0 0 1, 0 1 0, 0 0 0)), ((0 0 0, 0 1 0, 1 1 0, 0 0 0)))"

symbol = d.QgsPolygon3DSymbol()
symbol.setAddBackFaces(False)
symbol.setAltitudeBinding(1)
symbol.setAltitudeClamping(0)
symbol.setCullingMode(0)

renderer = d.QgsVectorLayer3DRenderer()
renderer.setSymbol(symbol)

materialSettings = d.QgsPhongMaterialSettings()
materialSettings.setAmbient(QColor(255,0,0))
materialSettings.setDiffuse(QColor(255,0,0))
materialSettings.setSpecular(QColor(255,0,0))
symbol.setMaterial(materialSettings)

layer = QgsVectorLayer("multipolygon?crs=EPSG:31469", "MULTIPOLYGON Z", "memory")
renderer.setLayer(layer)
feature = QgsFeature()
geometry = QgsGeometry.fromWkt(wkt)
feature.setGeometry(geometry)
layer.dataProvider().addFeatures([feature])
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayers([layer])
```

It shows no errors, it changes nothing.

I am using QGIS 3.12.0 Python console.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use [`setRenderer3D`](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsMapLayer.html#aeef71e3cf36dd5bbabd3b3c48d43ef1b) method of `QgsMapLayer`.

```
layer.setRenderer3D(renderer)
```

`QgsVectorLayer` inherits that method from `QgsMapLayer`.

Comment: The answer works. Dankeschön.